# Jamine how to mock interface with callback

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, knockout.js, jasmine, typescript-typings

I am new to Jamine test framework, Currently I have problem to mock an interface. Could any one help me on that?

the interface is like:

```
interface MessengerSubscribe {
    onSystemLoggedIn(callback: (data: INotLoggedinInfo) => void): MessengerSubscription;
    onSessionTimedOut(callback: () => void): MessengerSubscription;
    onHasEssBalance(callback: () => void): MessengerSubscription;
}
```

Here is what I tried which is not working.

```
let mockMessenger: MessengerStatic = {
        subscribe: {
            onSystemLoggedIn: () => <MessengerSubscription>
        }
    };
```

And here is the message description:

```
interface MessengerSubscription {
    dispose(): void;
}
```

Comment: I think you are mixing concepts. To mock an interface all you have to do is implement the methods defined in the interface. From your example it looks like you are trying to mock an Observable?  What is the context of your problem?

Comment: @shusson could you give me an example that how to implement the methods in the interface?

Answer (score 0):

A simple mock would look like:

```
let mockMessenger: MessengerSubscribe = {
    onSystemLoggedIn: (callback: any): any => {},
    onSessionTimedOut: (callback: any): any => {},
    onHasEssBalance: (callback: any): any => {}
};
```